# Use ".bytes" in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to parse the UniMag Pro swipe to get Track 1 and Track 2 data. I am using Swift and the SDK is written in Objective-C. For whatever reason I cannot figure out how to convert these to Swift, at least the bytes portion.

*Obj-C:*

```
const UInt8     *bytes= cardData.bytes;
const NSUInteger len  = cardData.length;
```

I tried variations of this and only had success with the length variable.

*Swift:*

```
let bytes:UInt8 = cardData.bytes
let len:NSInteger = cardData.length
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: What type is cardData?

Comment: @Darko Presumably NSData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you give the [Interacting with C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html) chapter a read.

For your question: you don't need to specify data type for variables in Swift

```
let bytes = cardData.bytes // type: UnsafePointer<UInt8> or UnsafePointer<Void>
let len = cardData.length // type: UInt or Int
```

I can't see your code for `cardData` so I can't tell the exact type for each variable.

Comment: I'd suggest showing him how he _should_ have said it: ` let bytes = cardData.bytes; let len = cardData.length`

Comment: Also `len` is Int, not UInt

Comment: And `bytes` is natively `UnsafePointer<Void>`

Comment: @matt that is what I was looking for, thanks a lot for your help. Can I upvote comment we well?

Comment: @Code Different I understood what you meant by "you don't need to specify the data type". Both of you helped, thanks.

Comment: @DG7 not to worry, you should just accept Code Different's answer. I'm hoping he'll edit it to include the points I made in my comment, but no harm done if he doesn't.